# How can I make repeating characters into a new line in a text file

Tags: shell, unix, sed, format, tr

I have a text file similar to this (This is how the data is extracted unfortunately):

```
asdf,10.vip0,sample_pool1,;;;;;;;;10.server1;;;;;;;;;;11.server2;;;;;;;;;;12.server3;;
asdf,10.vip1,sample_pool2,;;;;;;;;10.server1;;;;;;;;;;11.server2;;;;;;;;;;12.server3;;
asdf,10.vip2,sample_pool3,;;;;;;;;10.server1;;;;;;;;;;11.server2;;;;;;;;;;12.server4;;
```

Is there a command(s) I can use to get it formatted like this?

```
asdf,10.vip0,sample_pool1,10.server1
11.server2
12.server3
asdf,10.vip1,sample_pool2,10.server41
11.server42
12.server43
asdf,10.vip2,sample_pool3,10.server31
11.server32
12.server34
```

Comment: Can we assume that in the desired output (possibly in the sampe input) the `server41` and `server31` are typos? Otherwise please explain how they are derived from input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
$ sed 's/;;;\+//; s/;;;\+/\n/g; s/;;$//' file
asdf,10.vip0,sample_pool1,10.server1
11.server2
12.server3
asdf,10.vip1,sample_pool2,10.server1
11.server2
12.server3
asdf,10.vip2,sample_pool3,10.server1
11.server2
12.server4
```

it removes the first group of repeated semicolon `s/;;;\+//` then it replaces all the remaining groups with new-line `s/;;;\+/\n/g` and, finally, get rid of the two semicolon at the end `s/;;$//`

Answer (score 1):

***awk*** approach:

```
awk -F, '{ sub(/,;+/,",",$0); sub(/;+$/,"",$0); gsub(/;{3,}/,"\n",$0) }1' file
```

The output:

```
asdf,10.vip0,sample_pool1,10.server1
11.server2
12.server3
asdf,10.vip1,sample_pool2,10.server1
11.server2
12.server3
asdf,10.vip2,sample_pool3,10.server1
11.server2
12.server4
```